# WPF color picker - Add new custom color

Tags: c#, wpf, color-picker

I'm trying to add new a new custom color into the available colors of WPF color picker.

Code behind

```
this.colorPicker1.AvailableColors.Add(new ColorItem(Color.FromArgb(255, 153, 153, 187), "Custom"));
```

XAML

```xml
<exceedToolkit:ColorPicker Name="colorPicker1" DisplayColorAndName="True"/>
```

[image]

The problem is when I select this custom color, the textbox displays the hexadecimal value instead of the color's name ("Custom"),
is there a way for me to fix this?

Comment: According to the [Source Code](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Core/Utilities/ColorUtilities.cs) the name isn't determined by the entries in `AvailableColors` but the extension method `ColorUtilities.GetColorName`. Maybe it will work if you add your color to `ColorUtilities.KnownColors` too.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer can you please add this as an answer, I shall accept the same, this works!, downloaded the source code! Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above:

> According to the [Source Code](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/Core/Utilities/ColorUtilities.cs) the name isn't determined by the entries in `AvailableColors` but the extension method `ColorUtilities.GetColorName`. Maybe it will work if you add your color to `ColorUtilities.KnownColors` too.

A (dirty) workaround until the developers fix this would be to *ignore* that the `ColorUtilities` class is private:

```
public static class ColorItemExtension
{
    public static bool Register(this ColorItem colorItem)
    {
        if (colorItem.Color == null) return false;

        Assembly assembly = typeof(ColorPicker).Assembly;
        Type colorUtilityType = assembly.GetType("Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Core.Utilities.ColorUtilities");
        if (colorUtilityType == null) return false;

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = colorUtilityType.GetField("KnownColors");
        if (fieldInfo == null) return false;

        Dictionary<string, Color> knownColors = fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as Dictionary<string, Color>;
        if (knownColors == null) return false;
        if (knownColors.ContainsKey(colorItem.Name)) return false;

        knownColors.Add(colorItem.Name, (Color) colorItem.Color);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
var colorItem = new ColorItem(Color.FromRgb(1, 2, 3), "Almost black");
colorItem.Register();
colorPicker1.AvailableColors.Add(colorItem);
```

---

If this is important to you, you might want to consider bringing this issue to the developers attention [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)